Issues with SKIP LOCKED and MySQL Version Mismatch in MAMP
I'm facing a problem with my Symfony project while running on MAMP. The issue arises when I try to consume messages using the Doctrine transport with Symfony Messenger. I receive the following error:
`[Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\TransportException]
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SKIP LOCKED' at line 1
After some investigation, I found out that this error is related to the SKIP LOCKED feature, which is not supported in MySQL versions earlier than 8.0.1.
Here are the details of my setup:
Symfony Version: 7.1
Doctrine DBAL Version: 3.8.6
PHP Version: 8.2.0
MAMP Version: 6.9
Current MySQL Version: 5.7.39
In MAMP, I see a folder /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57, which indicates that it's using MySQL 5.7. However, I need to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 or higher to support SKIP LOCKED.`
Attempted to find a way to configure Doctrine to avoid using SKIP LOCKED without success.
Searched for methods to upgrade MySQL within MAMP but found that MAMP only provides MySQL 5.7 binaries.
How can I upgrade MySQL in MAMP to version 8.0 or higher?
Is there a way to configure Symfony Messenger with Doctrine to avoid using SKIP LOCKED?

MAMP 7.0 (2024-07-16) includes MySQL 8.0 according to their release notes. I am not a MAMP user, so I can't advise on how to upgrade an existing database. Refer to their documentation or support site.
